# How to create custom animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, jquery-animate

I want to create an animation using UIView's animateWithDuration, but I want to set a custom path rather than having it just go straight across. Is there any way that this can be accomplished without using multiple animations?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869509/how-to-animate-a-uibezierpath

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is to use core animation instead of basic UIView animation. It provides the flexibility you're looking for but is a bit more involved.
Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path) which has been answered.

Here is another [tutorial](http://www.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/03/iphone-animate-an-object-along-a-path/) to do the same.