# Animated RPM bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm actually new to iOS development with swift. So to make it short, i want to make this graphic in the Storyboard : [RPM DASH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmznc.png)

I'm trying to make rpm bar with received data in the background controlling the animation progress, and i have no idea from where to begin, and what kind of tool (Class, API, .. ) to use.

This is a video of what i want to reproduce (12 sec) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24cphMoAcyU ( only the animation of that bar)

I want to know :

- how to create that bar in xcode
- how to animate it with data in swift

already tried PaintCode, it may be possible to make it, but is there an xcode way.

So anybody please any help, showing me how things can be done. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `UIBezierPath` with a desired shape and then animate its `strokeEnd` property using `CABasicAnimation` .

See more about: [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) and [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/), as well as some posts with sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869509/how-to-animate-a-uibezierpath), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318918/how-to-make-my-uibezierpath-animated-with-cashapelayer), and [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/fun-with-cashapelayer/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! That s what i was looking for